# Zend 1.12 Session Encoding

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I am currently using Zend 1.12 for a hobby project and am using the  [Zend_Session](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.html) class in order to store data in sessions. I am currently storing an array into a session but this requires me to do the following for instance:

```
 $session->myArray = serialize($myArray);
 $session->saveSession();

 // later on
 $session = $this->getSession();
 $myArray = unserialize($session->myArray);
```

I do not really like having to serialize and unserialize this data, Does Zend 1 not have any sort of mechanism for handling this session encoding so that I don't have to do it on my end?

Just wondering, can't find anything in the documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Sessions serialize on their own, you should not need to do the extra step

Comment: My mistake... Thanks!

Comment: Please mark this question as solved or close it :).